# Codeigniter form_validation library error

Tags: php, authentication, controller, codeigniter-2

I am newbie to Codeigniter and trying to build a login page from the tutorial [codeigniter login](http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html). Now when I tried to login after entering my username and password, I am getting the following error.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Verifylogin::$form_validation
>
> Filename: controllers/verifylogin.php
>
> Line Number: 18

EDITED:

my `verifylogin.php` file is

```
    <?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
class Verifylogin extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('user');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        //$this->load->library('form_validation', 'form_validation', true/false);

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            redirect('login','refresh');
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('home','refresh');
        }
    }

    function check_database($password)
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $this->load->model('user');
        $result = $this->user->login($username,$password);

        if($result)
        {
            $sess_array = array();
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $sess_array = array('id'=>$row->id,'username'=>$row->username);

                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$sess_array);
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database','Invalid username or password');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Also where this `form_validation.php` file is located.

Comment: in system/libraries you can get `form_validation.php`

Comment: @rohitarora see the code block comment.

Comment: @Nitish: please copy & paste all code in your controller from class creation

Comment: Is there a problem with your callback function? Try commenting it out.
If that works then post your callback function, the problem is in there.

Comment: @Rooneyl I commented out that line but its same error !

Answer (score 1):

Please move all this code from index() function to the constructor,

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->model('user');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Because you are using the form_validation library in check_database() function also.

It should work now. :)

Comment: This time I am getting error like `Division by zero` for the line you mentioned.

Comment: I put `$this->load->library('form_validation', 'form_validation', true/false);`. The error I am getting is like `
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Division by zero

Filename: controllers/verifylogin.php

Line Number: 19
` NB: Line number 19 is the line you mentioned.

Comment: use like this i edited in code too $this->load->library('form_validation', 'form_validation', true);

Comment: edited my code. use like that.. Please move all this code from index() function to the constructor,    

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->model('user');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

Comment: in that change that initialization as i told before like, $this->load->library('form_validation', 'form_validation', true);

Comment: please check if library exists or not in library folder or application/library folder

Comment: it exists in system/libraries directory

Comment: please post your code again where you have moved the code to constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Can you put your login.php and home.php in your question?

i think you should use this

```
$this->load->view('login');
```

despite this

```
redirect('login','refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call helper function form before you use form validation

`$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));`

use this before you call library of form validation

Comment: I put that line before line number 18, but getting the same error .

Comment: put it before `$this->load->model('user');`

Comment: That's just not true. CodeIgniter loads the form helper in the form validation library constructor